# Error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am in my first class of Java programming and one of the assignments we were given was to create a value string which displays in reverse order separated by commas. I know I am probably missing something very simple, but after hours of trying I just don't know where I am going wrong?

My code works, however I keep getting this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 
    at ip2_jolley.IP2_Jolley.main(IP2_Jolley.java:148) 
Three, Two, One Java Result: 1
```

This is the code I am using:

```
String[] f = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
if (f.length > 0) System.out.print (f[2]);
for (int i = 1; i < f.length; i--){
    System.out.print(", " + f[i]); 
}
```

Comment: It won't let me click the up arrow so I edited to thank them.

Comment: ..and at the time I wasn't allowed to comment either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start your loop with int i = 1 and then reduce it by 1 every loop which will result in i being lower than 0.

Instead of using `int i = 1`, you probably want to use `int i = f.length`

**Edit**

What you wanted is probably this:

```
  String[] f = {"One", "Two", "Three","Four","Five"};

    //start at f.length - 1, continue until there is no item left
    for (int i = f.length-1; i >= 0; i--){

        //print current item
        System.out.print(f[i]);

        //if it is not the last item, print separator
        if(i>0){
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Edited with some explanation

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you start at 1, loop until the length of the array, but decrement i each time. That's a bit mixed up. What you want to do is start at the end of your array (so `f.length - 1`) and keep moving to the "left" of the array until you are at the beginning of it. So you want this:

```
for (int i = f.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
   System.out.print(f[i]); 
}
```

Comment: It would be fine if you explain *why*

Comment: Yes. You deserve my +1

Comment: Thank you changing the 1 loop to a 0 fixed the missing / wrong output =)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
```

Instead of:

```
for (int i = 1; i < f.length; i--)
```

Comment: I did not downvote the answer, but I imagine it is because the OP specifically is trying to display the values in reverse order.

Comment: Okay I will delete my answer then.

Comment: Thank you =) adding the ++ to replace the -- was what I needed.